# Is it posible to find text and get cell index i.e[row number and column numer ] in excel xssf document using java?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Find and get column and row value of that text using java.
In Xssf document.

Find location of the text searched in excel file using java

Comment: have you tried anything? is this a question or a statement?

Comment: cell = objSheet.getRow(34).getCell(7); this way i can set content ..But i dont know the exact position to retrieve because text places are not fixed

Comment: Text location changes .I need to find and replace as done in windows using CTRL+F and find text and replace it

Comment: Loop over all the rows and cells with http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator then check for the cell contents with http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is covered in the [Apache POI documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/), which you'd be very much suggested to read!

Specifically, in [iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) and in [getting the cell contents](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents)

Taking the code from there, and your need, we get:

```
String toFind = "needle in haystack";

Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("input.xlsx"));
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
for (Row row : sheet1) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        CellReference cellRef = new CellReference(row.getRowNum(), cell.getColumnIndex());

        // get the text that appears in the cell by getting the cell value and applying any data formats (Date, 0.00, 1.23e9, $1.23, etc)
        String text = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);

        // is it an exact match?
        if (toFind.equals(text)) {
           System.out.println("Text matched at " + cellRef.formatAsString());
        }
        // is it a partial match?
        else if (text.contains(toFind)) {
           System.out.println("Text found as part of " + cellRef.formatAsString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: XSSFWorkbook objWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(objFileInputStream);
XSSFSheet objSheet = objWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFCellStyle style = objWorkbook.createCellStyle();
DataFormatter formatter1 = new DataFormatter();    working fine bro!!

Comment: tried on XSSF with same code...